# Use sphinx vs MySQL on no text search query

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have this doubt:

Suppose I have a one big table with a relationship to to a smaller table of users.

The idea is to search in that really big table for dates bigger than a given date and order by a score (big int, for example), and obtain related user info at the same time.
The result of this query can change every 10 minutes or so.

So, there is no text search, but I have a really big table. Should I use sphinx (or other search engine) or should I just use some MySQL indexes?

If I use sphinx, it's sure that I can obtain really fast results; but maybe having the index refreshed, even with delta indexing, doesn't make a big difference with MySQL indexing. At the same time, the changes in the table are not necessary new inserts, but updates; and I have read that real time indexing and delta index can give problems.

Maybe it would be better to use MySQL indexes, and help with some kind of caching to avoid unnecessary queries .

Answer (score 0):

Just use MySQL, you definitely don't need Sphinx for what you are doing.

Comment: In general, do you only recommend Sphinx if text search is required?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for. It was not intended for data retrival as such (though it can be abused in that way)

Comment: Basically the only reason sphinx 'works quite well' for plain retrieval - ie so called 'full table scans' is sphinx - be design - keeps all the attribute data in memory. So queries are really fast due to it only accessing memory - no disk. If can persuade mysql to keep the whole database in memory will get comparable results. (although sphinx does do marginly better as sorting results than mysql does)

Comment: I don't agree that Sphinx only for full text search. Check out this article about how to use sphinx for Non-fulltext searches: http://kovyrin.net/2008/05/19/using-sphinx-for-non-fulltext-queries/

Comment: So, MySQL will be a good solution to that problem even when talking about a table with millions of rows?

Comment: I have mysql tables with tens of millions of rows. Shock horror! Like with anything it will take some tweaking to make it work well. (If where to use sphinx it would take some time and resources to make sphinx work well)

Comment: For example you mention filtering by date, maybe you can partition the table by date, so that many queries only hit the latest 'shard'.